# XSLT Group sibling elements between repeating attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been racking my brain for days now, and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to accomplish this. Take the following XML:

```
<Root>
   <container>
        <widget type="nav">
            <links>
                <tab type="label" header="Top Level Tab1"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab1"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab1"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab1"/>
                <tab type="label" header="Top Level Tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="label" header="Top Level Tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
            </links>
        </widget>
   </container>
</root>
```

What I need to do is transform this into a navigation area seperating at each tab with the type of "label" and placing the following siblings under it. For example

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="link for label">Top Level Header1</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu Link 1</li>
                <li>Submenu Link 1</li>
                <li>Submenu Link 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link for label">Top Level Header2</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu Link 2</li>
                <li>Submenu Link 2</li>
                <li>Submenu Link 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link for label">Top Level Header3</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu Link 3</li>
                <li>Submenu Link 3</li>
                <li>Submenu Link 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any guidance would certainly be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well XPath allows you to select the following or preceding sibling elements with the corresponding axes. And for efficiency you can use a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="subs" match="widget[@type = 'nav']/links/tab[@type = 'page']"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tab[@type = 'label'][1])"/>

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="container/widget[@type = 'nav']">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="links/tab[@type = 'label' and starts-with(@header, 'Top Level')]"/>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="links/tab[@type = 'label' and starts-with(@header, 'Top Level')]">
  <li>
    <a href="link for label">
      <xsl:value-of select="@header"/>
    </a>
    <div class="submenu">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('subs', generate-id())"/>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="links/tab[@type = 'page']">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="@header"/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That stylesheet transforms

```
<Root>
   <container>
        <widget type="nav">
            <links>
                <tab type="label" header="Top Level Tab1"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab1"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab1"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab1"/>
                <tab type="label" header="Top Level Tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab2"/>
                <tab type="label" header="Top Level Tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
                <tab type="page" header="submenu of tab3"/>
            </links>
        </widget>
   </container>
</Root>
```

into

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="link for label">Top Level Tab1</a><div class="submenu">
         <ul>
            <li>submenu of tab1</li>
            <li>submenu of tab1</li>
            <li>submenu of tab1</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="link for label">Top Level Tab2</a><div class="submenu">
         <ul>
            <li>submenu of tab2</li>
            <li>submenu of tab2</li>
            <li>submenu of tab2</li>
            <li>submenu of tab2</li>
            <li>submenu of tab2</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="link for label">Top Level Tab3</a><div class="submenu">
         <ul>
            <li>submenu of tab3</li>
            <li>submenu of tab3</li>
            <li>submenu of tab3</li>
            <li>submenu of tab3</li>
            <li>submenu of tab3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I have to modify a bit to fit the real stylesheet implications but this is 100% on point with what I needed! Thank You!